# Django (audio) html error

Tags: python, html, django

I have this project with django, everything working fine.
But when I go to a page where songs will be showen, and also the user have the option to play the songs, I get an error even if everything is working fine.
In the html page, when I remove the audio option " <'audio'>...<'/audio'>
I get no errors, but once I get it back, the error back with it, so the problem is with the <'audio'> tag I guess

The view :

```
@login_required()
def songs(request, filter_by=None):

    song_ids = []
    for album in Album.objects.filter(user=request.user):
        for song in album.song_set.all():
            song_ids.append(song.pk)
    users_songs = Song.objects.filter(pk__in=song_ids)

    if filter_by == 'favorites':
        users_songs = users_songs.filter(is_favorite=True)

    return render(request, 'music/songs.html', {
        'song_list': users_songs,
        'filter_by': filter_by,
    })
```

the bit of code of html page:

```
<td>
  <audio controls controlsList="nodownload">
         Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
   <source src="{{ song.audio_file.url }}" type="audio/wav">
 </audio>
</td>
```

and this is the error :

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>  "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-    32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py",
>  line 141, in run
>       self.handle_error()   File   "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-   packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py",
>   line 88, in handle_error
>      super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()   File   "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-  32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py",
>   line 368, in handle_error
>     self.finish_response()   File   "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-  32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py",
>   line 180, in finish_response
>       self.write(data)   File     "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-   32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py",
>   line 274, in write
>      self.send_headers()   File   "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-  32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py",
>  line 331, in send_headers
>     if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():   File   "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-  32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py",
>   line 344, in client_is_modern
>     return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9' TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
>
>  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-  32\lib\socketserver.py",
>   line 639, in process_request_thread
>  self.finish_request(request, client_address)   File      "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-  32\lib\socketserver.py",
>   line 361, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   File    "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-   32\lib\socketserver.py",
> line 696, in __init__
>     self.handle()   File "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py",
> line 155, in handle
> handler.run(self.server.get_app())   File   "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-   32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py",
>  line 144, in run
>      self.close()   File   "C:\Users\elmou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-  32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py",
>  line 35, in close
>      self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent AttributeError: '     NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
> ```

the error is so long, but it s the same over and over again

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: oh sorry, I added the error !

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you're doing a lot of unnecessary work in that view. Rather than looping through all the user's albums and then getting each song ID then querying for them all, you can just do `Song.objects.filter(album__user=request.user)`.

Comment: yes you're right (y)